# Swift function with do try block messes up UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, dispatch-async

I have 2 functions that when I call are messing up my `UIView`. I am calling them when a `Button` is tapped. Right before I call these two functions I call `View.isHidden = false` on a `UIView`. The problem is that if I call these two functions below, `.isHidden` is called a few seconds later and it looks very clunky.

```
@objc func addWishButtonTapped() {

    setUpLoadingAnimation() // this is where I call MyCustoView.isHidden = false

    self.crawlWebsite { // here I call the two functions below 
       ...
    }


}
```

**`crawlWebsite:`**

```
func crawlWebsite(finished: @escaping () -> Void){
    
    var html: String?
    guard let url = self.url else {
        return
    }
    let directoryURL = url as NSURL
    let urlString: String = directoryURL.absoluteString!
    // save url to wish
    self.wishView.link = urlString

    
    html = self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url)
    self.getContentFromHTML(html: html, url: url)

}
```

**Function 1:**

```
    //MARK: getHTMLfromURL
func getHTMLfromURL(url: URL?) -> String{
    
    let myURLString = url
    guard let myURL = myURLString else {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: url)) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return ""
    }

    do {
        let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
        return myHTMLString
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

**Function 2:**

```
    //MARK: getContent
func getContentFromHTML(html: String?, url: URL){
    
    do {
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html ?? "")
        
        if url.absoluteString.contains("amazon") {
            self.getAmazonImage(url: url)
        }
        
        self.getImages(doc: doc)
        
        // set price if not 0
        let price = Int(self.getPrice(doc: doc))
        if price != 0 {
            self.wishView.amount = Int(self.getPrice(doc: doc))
            self.wishView.priceTextField.text = self.wishView.updateAmount()
        }
        
    } catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
        print(message)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    
}
```

What can I do here so my view animation is working smooth? I tried embedding the two functions inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async` but I couldn't make it work... Any idea? What am I missing here?

Comment: please upload the code of crawlwebsite, hideloadingview, setuploading animation

Comment: Please upload some working code. What are the three dots in `crawlWebsite`? Why are you not calling the `finished` closure? And please upload the code of `setUpLoadingAnimation`. I hope you can understand that I can't help you if I cannot see the full code

Comment: I am calling some other things inside the `crawlWebsite-closure` but that is not the reason for the error. I am calling `finished` inside another functoin inside `crawlWebsite` I narrowed it down to the two functions above. If I remove the two functions above eveything works fine. So the error must be in the code above. What is it you need? :)

Comment: A minimum reproducible example. Anyway, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)` - this line is your problem.

You're not making the call to an external URL correct.
This `String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)` should be used only with a local file URL on the device, and not an external link. When you try to do this with an external URL, it blocks your main queue, thus you most probably have glitches.

Use `URLSession` for this. Read documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)

You could also use a pod like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: oh ok didn't expect it to be this kind of problem :/ Could you give me an example? Not quite sure on how to do this

Comment: can't I make it work with `dispatch.main.asnyc`?

Comment: `init(contentsOf: URL, encoding: String.Encoding)` is designed to be used with local URL (path url), and not an external URL. Try this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250234/8314394)

Comment: that was it. It is working now, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure `setUpLoadingAnimation()` is called before `self.crawlWebsite`, then the most logical/straightforward solution is to use a completion handler in setUpLoadingAnimation() like this

```
func setUpLoadingAnimation(completion: @escaping ()-> ()){
    //hideView
    completion()
}

setUpLoadingAnimation{

   self.crawlWebsite { 
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: that is not fixing it ... same behavior

Comment: I pretty sure it has something to do with `asynchronous calls`

Comment: `let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)`  this is causing the problem in **function 1**